# Cast JSON object to C# Object

Tags: asp.net, json, jquery

How do I map JSON object to C# object ?

```
  var Data = JSON.stringify({
                    FirstName: "sdfsdf",
                    LastName: "sdfsdf", Age: "sdfsdf", Descrp: "sdfsdf"
                });
```

for example converting Data to C# class with same properties.
I tried this :

```
 var Data = JSON.stringify({
                FirstName: "sdfsdf",
                LastName: "sdfsdf", Age: "sdfsdf", Descrp: "sdfsdf"
            });
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Services/CRUD.asmx/CreatePerson",
                data: Data,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg.d);

                }
            });
```

but when I checked with firebug this error returned :

```
{"Message":"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027PersonObj\u0027.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}
```

Comment: It's certainly possible.  Could you post the code for `CreatePerson`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can definitely do that, but you need to make sure the client-side object matches your server-side class structure, property names, and parameter name exactly.

It sounds like your server-side method is expecting a `PersonObj` parameter, but you aren't structuring it that way on the client-side.  Try something like this:

```
var Data = JSON.stringify({ 
  PersonObj: {
    FirstName: 'foo',
    LastName: 'bar',
    Age: 99,
    Descrp: 'foo person'
  }
});
```

I've written about doing this in-depth here: http://encosia.com/using-complex-types-to-make-calling-services-less-complex/

Comment: see you got guru of ajax to answer your questions i learned all this from his posts thanks dave ward!!!

Comment: @user648372: Thank you for the kind words. I hope I can live up to those compliments!

Answer (score 1):

What type is your PersonObj parameter? Assuming it is a Person like this:

```
public class Person
{
   public string FirstName { get;set;}
   public string LastName { get;set;}
   public string Age { get;set;}
   public string Descrp { get;set;}
}
```

Your WebService method signation should be:
    public static *returntype* CreatePerson(string jsonPersonObject) {}

And your Ajax data parameter should be:

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "Services/CRUD.asmx/CreatePerson",
       data: {'jsonPersonObject' : Data },
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (msg) {
          alert(msg.d);
       }
});
```

And then within CreatePerson you will have to parse the jsonPersonObject into a Person.

Common ways to do this are with [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) or `JavaScriptSerializer from System.Web.Extensions.dll`.  More in-depth info can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929434/how-do-i-parse-json) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-to-parse-json-in-c)

Comment: You shouldn't manually serialize or deserialize objects inside ASMX services. The framework will do this for you automatically if you take advantage of it (set the input parameters to the type you want it to deserialize to): http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/

Comment: Good to know.  Since very little context for the question was given, I'll leave the answer so when it's needed it will be available.

Answer (score 1):

do this:

```
 var context = new object();
 context.firstname = "sdfsdf";
 context.lname = "sdfsdf";
 context.age="sdfsdf";
 context.descrp= "sdfsdf"
 ajaxCall("functionname", context, ajaxCallSuccess, ajaxCallFailure, "pagename.aspx");
```

use json2 plugin to stringify your context obeject and pass this way

```
function ajaxCall(funtionname, reqObject, successFn, errorFn, theaspxPage) {

    var dataObject = JSON.stringify(reqObject);

    //Call the page method  
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        url: aspxPage + "/" + fn,
        contentType: "application/json;",
        data: "{'reqObject':" + dataObject + "}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: successFn,
        error: errorFn
    });
};
```

make sure your c# method is static and accepts an object
if you wanna pass as parameters just 
modify 
the ajaxcall data:dataobject, instead of reqobject:''