# how to get data from json

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do i parse json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929434/how-do-i-parse-json)

Please tell me the way to deserialize the json data in asp.net c#.
Actually I have a json data with two objects like:

```
{
    "errstr": "All downloded vedios ",
    "errcode": 0,
    "result": {
        "videos": [
            {
                "id": "22",
                "name": "Ashley",
                "price": "0.49",
                "size": "3712310"
            }
        ],
        "trailer": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "trailer_name": "charl1",
                "status": "1"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "trailer_name": "charl2",
                "status": "1"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here I have two objects videos and trailer. Please tell me the process to get get these data in my code.

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a class with nested members
for example json file

```
{
"GeminiURL":"https://gemini.com/Gemini"
,"Language":"en"
,"Log":{"Debug":true,"Info":true,"Warn":true,"FileName":"d:\\temp\\tfsgemini.log"}
}
```

is serializaed and deserialized with c# class

```
public class Settings
{
    public string GeminiURL;
    private LogSettings _log;
    public LogSettings Log
    {
        get { return _log = _log ?? new LogSettings(); }
        set { _log = value; }
    }
    public string Language;

    public Settings()
    {
        // defaule settings can be assigned here;
    }
}
public class LogSettings
{
    public bool Debug;
    public bool Info = true;
    public bool Warn = true;
    public string FileName;
}
```

and the deserialization code looks like:

```
public static T Load(string fileName)
{
    T t = new T();
        if (File.Exists(fileName))
            t = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize<T>(File.ReadAllText(fileName));
        else
            Save(t);
    return t;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON .NET - http://json.codeplex.com/